# Formula to create ID column for several Excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with 3 sheet. Each sheet is data from a questionnaire. Its dataset has a column with names, and the same names can appear again in the other sheets. i need a new column that makes an ID number for each name, and it should be the same number for each name in all sheets.
How can i do so?

Comment: Build an ID based on row number, first two letters of the name and first two letters of the day. Then use index() with match() to allocate the new ID to each user name.

Comment: And hat if several names have the same first two-three letters?

Comment: Check the answer and its update - two individuals are not likely to be on the same row, or you can use the first characters from each name...

Answer (score 0):

So something like this, which needs to be done on a "master" sheet so you have some control:

[image]

As for your comment about having the first 2 or 3 letters in the name the same then they won't be on the same row...

Or you can take the first letter from each name like so:

[image]

And showing use of index() with match():

[image]

As the columns can be left or right unlike vlookup.

Comment: Probably needs some lookup for the other sheets, this only takes in account the one sheet and will possibly give different ID's for the same name on different sheets. But using a row as part of the ID might make that a bit trickier.

Comment: @Notus_Panda I would only be creating names on one master sheet otherwise chaos will ensue... That master sheet can draw all the users together and use unique() to create the list... But without any clear example you can add as many conditions as you wish.

Comment: @Notus_Panda as for "some lookup" I would use index() with match() as stated in my comment above - many examples of the use of index() with match() exist.

Comment: I was saying "some lookup" to not assume your preference/OP's excel version, not trying to figure out what *could* be used :p As for your solution needing a master-file, that's a better solution than looking up in the other sheets ,you're right. If it's unclear how many sheets there will be or if more will be added later, VBA probably will become a necessity (in the future) to keep the Masterfile correct.